# Форматирование даты java

Tags: java, дата, format

Помогите разобраться. У меня есть два поля String dateFrom="01.04.2019"; и dateTo= "30.04.2019";
Мне нужно получить даты в данном диапазоне. При этом в таком же формате. Но у меня выводятся даты в формате 2019-04-01 и так далее.Как это правильно сделать.Не судите строго опыта у меня очень мало.`Ниже мой код.

```
String dateFrom = "01.04.2019";
    String dateTo = "30.04.2019";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(dateFrom, formatter);
    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(dateTo, formatter);
    System.out.println(startDate);
    System.out.println(endDate);
    Period period = Period.between(startDate, endDate);
    int a = period.getDays();
    System.out.println(period);

    for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++) {
        LocalDate[] listDays = {startDate.plusDays(i)};
        for (LocalDate d : listDays) {
            System.out.println(d);

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли собственно вызвать функцию форматирования в этом месте:

```
System.out.println(d)
```

В этом случае `println` использует `toString` объекта для конвертирования его в строку, а реализация метода `toString` в классе `LocalDate` использует формат как описано в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--):

> The output will be in the ISO-8601 format uuuu-MM-dd

Нужно так:

```
System.out.println(d.format(formatter))
```

Тогда будет использован формат из `formatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за помощь.